# 3ds Max TransNode not recognized as object

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We're having some problems accessing the parent object (the TransNode) in our Forge viewer application. The TransNode is the object/node which contains all the materials used in the object.

[image: Reference]

Our research found that TransNodes are not recognized as objects by the Forge Viewer. We can still access its materials (Mat0, Mat1, Mat3 etc), but not the parent (the TransNode).

Would it be possible to define the TransNodes as objects in the API or is there any workaround we could use? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It would be difficult to say without having a sample scene. Can you prepare a sample scene with that asset only, check if this issue persists and attach it (give a link), so I could check it and maybe come up with a solution. 
Reasons could vary, maybe it is an XRef?

Comment: Thanks, sounds great. Denis.grigor (at) autodesk.com?

Comment: Yes, I will look into it, but I will have to write a "generic" answer here, for others to benefit too.

Answer (score 0):

If in a 3ds Max scene, an object has applied a Multi-Material, upon translation, for each channel there will be created a subcomponent. 
This becomes handy when you want to create selectable parts of a mesh, without breaking apart the mesh.

However, if you want to avoid this subcomponent selection and select the entire object upon subcomponent selection, there are 2 approaches:

1. At 3ds Max level, before translating the scene, replace the Multi-Material with a Basic/Single Material. To keep the texture/colour, just bake the MultiMat into a bitmap and use it as diffuse colour in the Basic Material.
2. At Forge Viewer level, you could tailor selection using algorithm like:
       ***if I am selecting a child, select automatically the parent***.
   This is done by subscribing to selection event and at minimum, the code could look like this:

```js
let viewer = viewerApp.getCurrentViewer();
let tree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;

viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT,
    (event) => {
    if (event.selections[] != undefined) {
         let selectedNode = event.selections[0].dbIdArray[0];
         console.log("selected a node with id = ", selectedNode);
         if (tree.nodeAccess.getNumChildren(selectedNode) == 0) {
                 let parentId = tree.nodeAccess.getParentId(selectedNode);
                 console.log("parent of the selected node is ", parentId)
                 viewer.select(parentId);
        }
    }
})
```

Thus, any selection of a "leaf", will automatically select the parent of that "leaf" along with all that is under the parent node.

The second approach is derived from one of our blogpost discussing the idea of [Controlling components selection in the Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/controlling-components-selection-viewer).